# How to drop a single value in a row?

Tags: python, pandas

I am performing a balanced panel regression. Since several variables have missing values, I need to drop them equally to maintain the balance. However, when I drop a NA, the whole row is removed, while it may contain valuable information for other variables. When I do my calculations with the NA or Inf values, which are both invalid, it treats them as zero or inf.  How can I drop the NA value, or skip NA in the calculations?

I dropped the rows. I tried to skip them in the calculations, but without success.

An example calculation of Return on assets. Net_income and Total_assets both have missing values. While the row itself, containing other variables, do have valid values.

```
df['ROA'] = df['net_income'] / df['total_assets']
```

Comment: I am not seeing the issue.  If you have missing values in `net_income` and `total_assets`, what value do you expect to get for `ROA` other than `nan`?  I.e. if row 3 of `net_income` is `nan`, and row 5 of `total_assets` is also `nan`, you should expect both rows 3 and 5 of `ROA` to be `nan`.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I forgot to mention that there are also other variables, which I want to keep while removing the NAN values.

Answer (score 0):

Columns need to have same size.
you can use Numpy:

**if you have:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[1,np.nan],[1,2]],columns=['id','age'])
```

**you can use np.divide**

```
A = np.divide(df['id'].values,df['age'].values)
```

**the answer is:**

```
array([0.5, nan, 0.5])
```

**now you can drop with:**

```
A = A[~np.isnan(A)]
```

**then you have this:**

```
[0.5 0.5]
```

Comment: Do they have the same size, but sometimes, they miss a value. Therefore, making it still balanced, since they all are lacking some values in some rows. I want to consolidate them and even out the results.

Comment: i understand what you say. there is a lot of solution for this issue like AI solutions.

Comment: if its doesn't matter to drop a row then you do this solution its work properly.

Comment: Thank you! But it does matter. I just want to drop the value and not the whole column/row.

Comment: numpy can handle nan parameter. if you divide with numpy then you can drop nan values.